# Оформление словаря в txt файле и вычитывание значений из этого файла

Tags: python, словари

Появилась идея сделать программу, которая могла бы случайным образом выбирать игру.

В целом что есть:

1. Файл с перечнем жанров игр в формате

   ```
   RPG
   Action
   MMORPG
   и т.д. каждый новый жанр с новой строки
   ```
2. Есть перечень игр в формате

   ```
   RPG = Dragon_Age, The_Elder_Scrolls_Skyrim
   Shooter = Bulletstorm, Splinter_Cell
   MMORPG = Lineage_2, Aion
   Action = Grand_Theft_Auto_V, Watch_Dogs
   Racing = Need_For_Speed_Payback, Blur
   и т.д. каждый новый жанр с новой строки
   ```
3. И есть вот такой код.

```
#-*- coding:cp1251 -*-

from random import randint

GenreList = []
FilteredGames = []
GameList = dict()
selected_genre = str()
selected_game = str()


def GenreSelection():
    genre_file = open('genres.txt')
    for line in genre_file.readlines():
        GenreList.append(line.strip())
    rand_range_genres = len(GenreList)
    print(rand_range_genres)
    selected_genre = GenreList[random.randint((rand_range_genres-rand_range_genres)-1,rand_range_genres)]
    print(selected_genre)
    genre_file.close()
    
def GameSelection():
    #genre = "".join(selected_genre)
    games_file = open("games.txt")
    onstring = games_file.read().split("\n")
    for item in onstring:
       key = item.split(" ")[0]
       value = item.split(" ")[1:]
       GameList[key] = value
    
    if item == selected_genre:
        FilteredGames.append(key[value])
    rand_drange_games = len(FilteredGames)
    print(FilteredGames)
    print(rand_range_games)
    print(GameList)
    #selected_game = GameList[random.randint((rand_range_games-rand_range_games)-1,rand_range_games)]
    #print(selected_game)
    games_file.close()

input('Для генерации жанра нажмите Enter')
GenreSelection()
input('Для генерации игры нажмите Enter')
GameSelection()
```

Собственно в чем вопрос:

Проблема в том, что данные из списка считываются, потому что `print(GameList)` выводит в формате:

```
{'RPG': ['Dragon_Age,', 'The_Elder_Scrolls_Skyrim'], 'Shooter': ['Bulletstorm,', 'Splinter_Cell'], 'MMORPG': ['Lineage_2,', 'Aion'], 'Action': ['Grand_Theft_Auto_V,', 'Watch_Dogs'], 'Racing': ['Need_For_Speed_Payback,', 'Blur']}
```

(Баг с запятыми исправляется их убиранием и оставлением пробела)

Но эти списки в квадратных скобках он не добавляет через append в переменную FilteredGames.

Возможно, я как-то не так оформил сам словарь? Есть ли какие-то правила оформления словарей в текстовом файле? Или их надо оформлять так же как в самом питоне через фигурные скобки и двоеточия?

Из-за нулевой длины списка, последующие закомментированные строки тоже выдают ошибку

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Что должен делать код и что он делает на самом деле? Какой еще баг с запятыми? [ask]

Comment: Слушай, я не совсем понимаю, зачем тебе все эти сложности со словарями? Всё очень просто. Берешь, записываешь в каждой строчке txt файла одну игру. Затем в программе импортируешь модуль random, считываешь из файла построчно (games = file.readlines()), и делаешь random.choice(games). И всё!

Comment: Глеб
Тут вопрос еще в сортировке по жанру. То есть сначала выбирается жанр, а потом игра. Хотя возможно проще будет действительно сделать список игр без сортировки по жанрам и не **ать себе мозг...

Comment: Чтобы отметить вопрос решённым, выберите наиболее полезный ответ и поставьте зелёную галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Вот готовый десериализатор который вернёт словарь, где ключи - жанр, значения - список игр. Думаю, подобного ответа достаточно, ибо остальной код у вас готов.

```
import re

def deserialize(file_path):
  
    with open(file_path) as f:
        data = f.read()

    result = {}

    for line in data.splitlines():
        if line.strip() == '':
            continue
    
        key, values = line.split(' = ')
        values = re.split(', *', values)
        result[key] = values
    
    return result
```

Данная функция принимает на вход путь до файла который нужно загрузить.

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю всех за ответы, немного укоротил код но пока без использования JSON.. Так-как еще не особо в этом шарю.
Пока открываю txt Файлы, но уже разобрался с фильтрацией) + там немного по другому будет выглядеть всё так как буду делать GUI софтину в которой уже буду использовать функцию открытия определенного файла с определенным жанром и выбора оттуда рандомной игры)

Всем спасибо)

Comment: Этот ответ не содержит решения вопроса. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте его, внесите необходимую информацию, покажите код.

Answer (score -1):

Данный код вполне рабочий

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import random


def open_file():
    with open("/home/usr/tratata/game_list.txt", "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        return data

def pick_game(data):
    pick = random.choice(data).rstrip()
    return pick

def main():
    data = open_file()
    game = pick_game(data)
    print(f"Сегодня я один буду играть в {game}, у меня нет друзей :(")

main()
```